# How can I use apply with pandas rolling_corr()

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I posted this a while ago but no one could solve the problem.

first let's create some correlated DataFrames and call `rolling_corr()`, with `dropna()` as I am going to sparse it up later and no min_period set as I want to keep the results robust and consistent with the set window

```
 hey=(DataFrame(np.random.random((15,3)))+.2).cumsum()
 hoo=(DataFrame(np.random.random((15,3)))+.2).cumsum()
 hey_corr= rolling_corr(hey.dropna(),hoo.dropna(), 4)
```

gives me

```
In [388]: hey_corr

Out[388]: 

   0        1        2
0  NaN      NaN      NaN
1  NaN      NaN      NaN
2  NaN      NaN      NaN
3  0.991087 0.978383 0.992614
4  0.974117 0.974871 0.989411
5  0.966969 0.972894 0.997427
6  0.942064 0.994681 0.996529
7  0.932688 0.986505 0.991353
8  0.935591 0.966705 0.980186
9  0.969994 0.977517 0.931809
10 0.979783 0.956659 0.923954
11 0.987701 0.959434 0.961002
12 0.907483 0.986226 0.978658
13 0.940320 0.985458 0.967748 
14 0.952916 0.992365 0.973929
```

now when I sparse it up it gives me...

```
hey.ix[5:8,0] = np.nan
hey.ix[6:10,1] = np.nan
hoo.ix[5:8,0] = np.nan
hoo.ix[6:10,1] = np.nan
hey_corr_sparse = rolling_corr(hey.dropna(),hoo.dropna(), 4)
hey_corr_sparse

Out[398]: 

   0        1        2
0  NaN      NaN      NaN
1  NaN      NaN      NaN
2  NaN      NaN      NaN
3  0.991273 0.992557 0.985773
4  0.953041 0.999411 0.958595
11 0.996801 0.998218 0.992538
12 0.994919 0.998656 0.995235
13 0.994899 0.997465 0.997950
14 0.971828 0.937512 0.994037
```

chucks of data are missing, it looks like we only have data where the `dropna()` can form a complete window across the dataframe

I can solve the problem with a ugly iter-fudge as follows...

```
hey_corr_sparse = DataFrame(np.nan, index=hey.index,columns=hey.columns)
for i in hey_corr_sparse.columns:
    hey_corr_sparse.ix[:,i] = rolling_corr(hey.ix[:,i].dropna(),hoo.ix[:,i].dropna(), 4)
hey_corr_sparse

Out[406]: 

   0        1        2
0  NaN      NaN      NaN
1  NaN      NaN      NaN
2  NaN      NaN      NaN
3  0.991273 0.992557 0.985773
4  0.953041 0.999411 0.958595
5  NaN      0.944246 0.961917
6  NaN      NaN      0.941467
7  NaN      NaN      0.963183
8  NaN      NaN      0.980530
9  0.993865 NaN      0.984484
10 0.997691 NaN      0.998441
11 0.978982 0.991095 0.997462
12 0.914663 0.990844 0.998134
13 0.933355 0.995848 0.976262
14 0.971828 0.937512 0.994037
```

Does anyone in the community know if it is possible make this an array function to give this result, I've attempted to use .apply but drawn a blank, is it even possible to .apply a function that works on two data structures (hey and hoo in this example)?

many thanks, LW

Comment: If there are NaNs in a column, should the correlation window disregard them? Because in that case for example the correlations on index 11 are not calculated based on the same rows for different columns?

Comment: it really depends on data task and why there are NaN's, in my example I am specifically excluding data as NaN's (vs winsorising) and taking advantage of Pandas treatment NaN's in computation.

Comment: Yes I know it can depend. But was just asking, because if you want to propagate the NaNs, you can just do rolling_cor without the dropna: `rolling_corr(hey,hoo, 4)`

Comment: tried to do this without dropna()and with min periods but didn't give me the correct result, if you can make it work would love to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try this:

```
>>> def sparse_rolling_corr(ts, other, window):
...     return rolling_corr(ts.dropna(), other[ts.name].dropna(), window).reindex_like(ts)
... 
>>> hey.apply(sparse_rolling_corr, args=(hoo, 4))
```